# How to connect mysql using ssh tunnel and dedicated IP

Tags: mysql, ssh, mysql-workbench

I have been working with mysql for a while in localhost and now I decided to install it on a different workstation within my private network.

In order to achieve my objective I executed the following:

1. I installed it on a Linux workstation (mysql 5.6) with `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6`
2. MySQL only listens for localhost calls; to change that, I had to open the folling file:

   $ sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
3. Changed the following line to

   bind-address = 10.3.16.1 (Server IP address)
4. Then I created a new user within the database as follow

   mysql> CREATE USER 'user1234'@'10.3.16.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

   mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user1234'@'10.3.16.1'
       ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;

   mysql> CREATE USER 'user1234'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

   mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user1234'@'%'
       ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
5. In order to connect my client to the server without typing the password I created an RSA key

   $ ssh-keygen -t rsa
6. I pushed the key to the server where mysql database sits

   $ ssh-copy-id server@10.3.16.1
7. Tested the connection without password

   $ ssh server@10.3.16.1
8. So far so good! Now I am trying to connect mysql Workbench to the server but apparently I did something wrong.

[image: MySQL Connection]

These are the errors

[image: MySQL Error 1]

[image: MySQL Error 2]

Would be grateful if you can help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the SSH Key File Path and it worked well